# Blender is deleting vertices when I fracture the object?

Tags: mesh, vertices, cell-fracture

[image]

Dear Blender Community,
I watched this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnmzQfduXes (2:19). I want to fracture my model same  as the guy from the vid. Somehow when I fracture my model the result is Very unsharp and the Crack is to edgy. I think this is because blender is deleting vertices from my mesh. I don`t know how to fix this problem. PLease help me I would be very gratefull !!! :)